# JavaScript: saving all transformations of canvas, (taking into account the save and restore) for deferred drawing did not work as expected

Tags: canvas, transformation

I want to remember all the transformations of the canvas so that I can then apply them to the saved values ​​for drawing. To do this, I created a wrapper over the context that calculates all transformations and uses them when calling the drawing method, but the result is not as expected, I can not understand where I was mistaken.[

```js
const canvas1 = document.querySelector('#canvas1');
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
const canvas2 = document.querySelector('#canvas2');
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

class ContextMemory {
  constructor(context, contextTest){
    this.context = context;
    this.contextTest = contextTest;
    this.init();
    this.save();
  }

  init(){
    this.currentAngle = 0;
    this.currentTranslateX = 0;
    this.currentTranslateY = 0;
    
    this.stackTransformations = [];
    this.bones = {} 
    this.rects = {} 
  }

  translate(x, y){
    this.context.translate(x, y);
    //this.currentTransformation[4] += x; 
    //this.currentTransformation[5] += y
    this.currentTranslateX += x;
    this.currentTranslateY += y;

  }
  
  rotate(rad){
    this.context.rotate(rad);
    this.currentAngle += rad;
    //this.currentTransformation[0] += Math.cos(rad);
    //this.currentTransformation[1] += Math.sin(rad);
    //this.currentTransformation[2] -= Math.sin(rad);
    //this.currentTransformation[3] += Math.cos(rad);

  }
  
  save(){
    this.context.save();
    this.stackTransformations.push({
      rad: this.currentAngle,
      xt: this.currentTranslateX,
      yt: this.currentTranslateY,
    });
    
  }

  restore(){
    this.context.restore();
    let o = this.stackTransformations.pop();
      this.currentAngle = o.rad;
      this.currentTranslateX = o.xt;
      this.currentTranslateY = o.yt;
    }

  rect (rectName, x, y, w, h){
    this.circle(this.context, rectName, this.currentTranslateX, this.currentTranslateY)
    this.context.rect(x, y, w, h);
    this.context.stroke();
    this.saveRect(rectName, x, y, w, h);
  }
  
  saveRect(rectName, x, y, w, h) {
    this.rects[rectName] = {
      rad: this.currentAngle,
      xt: this.currentTranslateX,
      yt: this.currentTranslateY,
      
      x, y, w, h
    }
  }

  drawRects() {
    Object.keys(this.rects).forEach((key)=>{
      //this.contextTest.save();
        let stored = this.rects[key];   

        this.contextTest.setTransform(Math.cos(stored.rad), 
        Math.sin(stored.rad), -Math.sin(stored.rad), Math.cos(stored.rad), stored.xt, stored.yt);

        this.contextTest.rect(stored.x, stored.y, stored.w, stored.h);
        this.contextTest.stroke();
        
        this.circle(this.contextTest, key, stored.translateX, stored.translateY)
      //this.contextTest.restore();  
    })
  }

  circle(context, text){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, 7, 0 , 1.7 * Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
    this.text(context, text, 0 , 0, 'green')
    context.stroke();
  }

  text(context, text, x, y, color){
    context.fillStyle = color;
      context.font = "15px Georgia";
      context.fillText(text, x, y-10); 
      context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = "black";
  }
  
  stroke(){
    this.context.stroke();
  } 

  tryExample(){
    try{
        let matrix = this.context.currentTransform;
        matrix.a = 1;
        matrix.b = 0;
        matrix.c = 0;
        matrix.d = 1;
        matrix.e = 0;
        matrix.f = 0;
     } catch(error) {
        console.error(`MDN EXAMPLE ERROR: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true or
                 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/currentTransform`, error);
     } 
  }

}



//ctm.tryExample();
const ctm = new ContextMemory(ctx1, ctx2);
ctm.save()
  ctm.translate(80, 80);
  ctm.rect('1',0, 0, 150, 100);
  ctm.stroke();
  ctm.save()
    ctm.rotate(.2);
    ctm.translate(5,5);
    ctm.rect('2',0, 0, 20, 10);
    ctm.stroke();
    ctm.save()
      ctm.rotate(.9);
      ctm.translate(100,100);
      ctm.rect('3', 0, 0, 30, 30);
      ctm.stroke();
    ctm.restore()
    ctm.rotate(.4);
    ctm.translate(-50,-50);    
    ctm.rect('4',0, 0, 15, 10);
    ctm.stroke();
  ctm.restore()
ctm.restore()
ctm.drawRects();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js" defer></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <canvas id= "canvas1" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
   <canvas id ="canvas2" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much time and won't go into details but just point out your misconception and how to fix it.

If you do `ctx.translate(10,10); ctx.rotate(π); ctx.translate(-10,-10); ctx.rotate(-π);` you are not at `0,0` like your *ContextMemory* expects.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.scale(4, 4); // so we can see better
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1); // 0,0 => green

ctx.translate(10,10);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
ctx.translate(-10,-10);
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI);

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1); // not 0,0 anymore
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #EEE}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"><canvas>
```

All transformations are cumulative, so the best way to handle this is to have a transform matrix, that you'll update at every call.

e.g given a base matrix

```
m = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
// [scaleX, skewX, skewY, scaleY, translateX, translateY]`
```

- the `translate(x, y)` operation will do `m[4] += x; m[5] += y;`
- the `rotate(rad)` one will do `m[0] += cos(rad); m[1] += sin(rad); m[2] -= sin(rad); m[3] += cos(rad);`

And every coordinates used by any operations should then get multiplied by this transformation matrix.

Now, there is a convenient method in the canvas2d API which allows us to actually set directly the current transformation matrix of the context: [`setTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform). This method will reset the transform matrix, meaning, it won't accumulate like other transform methods.

And we should even have [ctx.currentTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/currentTransform) which would allow us to grab the current transform, but this is unfortunately still only supported by Chrome and Edge...

Comment: Thank. I watched this article (https://www.w3resource.com/html5-canvas/html5-canvas-matrix-transforms.php) and tried to apply it but it didn't work out. Either there is no image or it is distorted and on an enlarged scale. I watched https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/currentTransform Error: 'a' of undefined) All shapes are a skeleton where each part depends on the previous one, so I need the sum of all the transformations to it, I do not know how to get it.